# Getting Dropdownlist Update Value in Gridview Using Object Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which one of the column contains dropdownlist. The Item in dropdownlist come from **daftarproperti.cs** (an object data source class).
The problem here is whenever i update the row, the update value for this dropdownlist become 0.

This is the excerpt of my aspx:

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gv_dalamlokasi_jadwal"
                    CssClass="table table-bordered"
                    runat="server"
                    BackColor="White"
                    BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                    BorderStyle="None"
                    BorderWidth="1px"
                    CellPadding="3"
                    DataKeyNames="tugasID"
                    ShowFooter="True"
                    OnRowDataBound="gv_dalamlokasi_jadwal_OnRowDataBound"

                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ds_dalamlokasi_rincian">
                    <Columns> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Peran" SortExpression="Peran">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_peran"
                                    runat="server"

                                    DataTextField="nmperan"
                                    DataValueField="kdperan">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_peran" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nmperan") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the aspx.cs code:

```
protected void gv_dalamlokasi_jadwal_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //DataRowView dRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddlperan = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_peran");
                if (ddlperan != null)
                {
                    ddlperan.DataSource = daftarproperti.TampilkanPeran();
                    ddlperan.DataValueField = "kdperan";
                    ddlperan.DataTextField = "nmperan";
                    ddlperan.DataBind();
                    DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                    //ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
                    ddlperan.SelectedValue = dr["kdperan"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the daftarproperti.cs code:

```
public class daftarproperti
{public static List<daftarproperti> TampilkanPeran()
    {
        List<daftarproperti> Listperan = new List<daftarproperti>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nikita_app"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT*FROM [nikitaapp].[dbo].[vt_peran]", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                daftarproperti bacaperan = new daftarproperti();
                bacaperan.kdperan = (int)rdr["kdperan"];
                bacaperan.nmperan = rdr["nmperan"].ToString();
                Listperan.Add(bacaperan);
            }
        }

        return Listperan;

    }
```

What should i do to make the code work when updateing?

Comment: did u put debugger your `daftarproperti.TampilkanPeran()` returning List from DB ?  `SELECT*FROM` is working in Query?

Comment: Yes of course @Ganesh_Devlekar , if i run the query, it will return two column, kdperan and nmperan.

Comment: show some code where you are updating ?

Comment: https://github.com/ansyaku/webdesign/blob/master/update @Ganesh_Devlekar